# Nested promises - IndexedDB transactions using Dexie

Tags: javascript, promise, indexeddb, dexie

I have the following code where the modifying the db item base on an inner promise is not working.

```
    $('input[type=checkbox][name=checklist]:checked').each(function()
    {
        var collection=db.items.where("name").equals(checkbox.val());
        var success;
        collection.modify(function(item){
             var invokePromise;
                //invokePromise = a fucntion that returns a promise 
                //this invokepromise function needs the item from the db.

             invokePromise.then(function(thirdPartyResponse){
                    item.date=new Date();
                    item.attempts= item.attempts+1; <-- this is not being updated.
            }).catch(function(error){
                    delete this.value; <-- this is also not deleted

            });
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: What does "inner promise is not working" mean? Does it throw error? You should provide more info about output..

Comment: The item in the collection is not either modified or deleted. I can see those lines being executed but when I query the indexedDb the value is still same as before.

Comment: why don't you use async/await?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering [@David Fahlander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1282923/david-fahlander) answer that `Collection.modify()` must synchronously update the item, you should collect the async responses first and after alter the database. You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to asynchronously collect the responses from the `invokePromise` and modify the database in one go afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

A callback given to [Collection.modify()](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.modify()) must synchronously update the item. You could also optimize the query using anyOf() instead of equasls. Here's an example that examplifies another strategy:

```js
function yourAction () {
  const checkedValues = $('input[type=checkbox][name=checklist]:checked')
    .toArray() // Convert to a standard array of elements
    .map(checkBox => checkBox.value); // Convert to an array of checked values

  return invokePromise.then(thirdPartyResponse => {
    return db.items.where("name").anyOf(checkedValues).modify(item => {
      item.date = new Date();
      ++item.attempts;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error("Failed to update indexedDB");
      throw error;
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    // Handle an errors from invokePromise
    // If an error occurs, delete the values. Was this your intent?
    console.error("Error occurred. Now deleting values instead", error);
    return db.items.where("name").anyOf(checkedValues).delete();
  });
}
```

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear. I need to use the db item in my `invokePromise` function.

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve all the entries, wait for the promises and then update them seperately:

```
 (async function() {
   const entries = await db.items
       .where("name").equals(checkbox.val())
       .toArray();

   for(const entry of entries) {
     //...
     await invokePromise;
     await db.items.put(entry);
  }
})();
```

You might want to parallelize the whole thing with `entries.map` and `Promise.all` and `Table.putAll`.